# JSON.py is deleting my json file when I run code

Tags: python, json

I am helping my teacher by creating a game where the k-2 kids can learn their passwords, I added this json file to create a save for the teacher so he doesn't have to re-add all the computers names and passwords... But when I run my code, the json file gets wiped, and I lose all of my code... Luckily I had backups but I cant have it erase for my teacher.

Python Code:

```
import json

with open("accounts.json", "w") as f:
  accountData = json.dumps(f)

type(accountData)
```

JSON:

```
{ // not real names and passwords for security
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "uname": "scarlett",
      "pword": "k,",
      "points": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "uname": "santiago",
      "pword": "k,",
      "points": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "uname": "harper",
      "pword": "k,",
      "points": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You are opening a file in write mode (w). That will overwrite the file (and make it empty).

Comment: Should I use "a"?

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong use of the `json.dump` method.
Here is part of the help to `json.dump` in python at version 3.7.6.

```tex
Help on function dump in module json:

dump(obj, fp, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)
    Serialize ``obj`` as a JSON formatted stream to ``fp`` (a
    ``.write()``-supporting file-like object).
```

The first parameter should be the `dict` object which contains the names and passwords, and **you missed this parameter**.
And the parameter `f` should be in the second place.

Comment: This still doesn't address the issue that was mentioned, i.e. with `dump` the file still gets overwritten and data is lost.

Comment: It does. Thank you for your help :)